# Knockout Components - Custom Component Loaders

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components, systemjs

I'm using Knockout Components and with [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) for module loading.

I have a custom component loader:

```
var myComponentLoader = {
  loadComponent: function(name, componentConfig, callback) {
    System.import(componentConfig.myLoader)
    .then(function(loadedComponent) {

      var result = {
        template: ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(loadedComponent.componentTemplate),
        createViewModel: loadedComponent.MyComponentViewModel
      }
      callback(result);
    })
    // .catch(function(myError){
    //   alert(myError);
    //   callback(null);
    // });
    }
};

// Register it
ko.components.loaders.unshift(myComponentLoader);

ko.components.register('my-component', { myLoader: './app/components/components' });
```

But this fails with the following message:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"}

This is how my result.template looks like:

```
<div>This is my component template</div>
<div data-bind="text: myName"></div>
```

This is how my result.createViewModel looks like:

```
 function MyComponentViewModel(params) {
        // Set up properties, etc.
        this.myName = ko.observable("Amy Smith");
        this.doSomething(params);
        this.boundAt = ko.observable(moment().format());
    }
```

Here is the full error:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.ko.utils.cloneNodes (http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:270:48)
    at cloneTemplateIntoElement (http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3644:41)
    at null.callback (http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3621:21)
    at Function.ko_subscribable_fn.notifySubscribers (http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:1103:38)
    at http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3151:54
    at http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3169:21
    at http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3198:29
    at eval (http://localhost:8081/app/components/components-bootstrapper.js!eval:32:13)
    at O (http://localhost:8081/lib/es6-module-loader.js:7:7439)
    at K (http://localhost:8081/lib/es6-module-loader.js:7:7071)
```

Comment: Have you seen the http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html article, "Implementing a custom component loader" section?

Comment: Hi @TSV I was able to create custom component loaders as mentioned above and that was the documentation I used. My issue is that the syntax I want to use works with RequireJS but I need to make it work with SystemJS. Thanks

Comment: You need to implement the `loadComponent` method (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#functions-you-can-implement). There you can do anything with the `componentConfig` and you can add your custom config parsing logic there. It would be easier to help you if you would post your current custom loader code.

Comment: Hi @nemesv, I've tried your suggestion. I'm closer! I also updated the question with the code I'm using as per your request. Thanks

Comment: The template property has to contain an array of DOM nodes: so try with `template: ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(loadedComponent.componentTemplate)`

Comment: Thanks again @nemesv. Now I get an error in the viewModel. Is there something similar to what you suggested for the template that I need to apply to the viewModel? 
 Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.MyComponentViewModel [as createViewModel] (http://localhost:8081/components.js!eval:7:14)
    at createViewModel (http://localhost:8081/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3651:123)
    at null.callback (http://localhost:8081/lib/bower/knockout@3.3.0/dist/knockout.js:3622:46)
    at Function.ko_subscribable_fn.notifySubscribers

Comment: Please post your complete `components.js` because in your current sample you have a non definied method `doSomething`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide your custom configuration handling logic you need to implement the `loadComponent` method as described in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#functions-you-can-implement).

However you need to watch out what you return from it, because according to the documentation:

- The `template` property has to contain an **array of DOM nodes**: so if your loader loads a string you need to parse it first with:

  ```
  template: ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(loadedComponent.componentTemplate)
  ```
- The `createViewModel` has to contain a **factory function**, so not directly your view model constructor function. So you need to wrap it with

  ```
  createViewModel: function (params, componentInfo) { return new loadedComponent.viewModel(params, componentInfo); }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've made a working gist for systemjs load: https://gist.github.com/jpolvora/3712241510e1b1023fbb00d0285dedf8